# Questions About Database

Tags: database, entity-framework

I write chat in C# with Entity Framework

This is my code

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }

    public List<UserMessages> userMessages { get; set; }
}

public class UserMessages
{
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public long ChatMateId { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework code-first forced me to put on the `Id` field in `UserMessages` class attribute `[Key]` , I don't need this field at all because `UserMessages` is weak entity that will point to `id` of `User`

Can I delete `long Id` from sql table after ef create the table, without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. EF requires that all tables have a `[Key]` on them, or it will blow up. Even when mapping to SQL Views (as I've learned the hard way, believe me).

In your case, you should actually be using a proper Foreign Key in that table also, like so:

```
 public class UserMessages
 {
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public long ChatMateId { get; set; }

    public string text { get; set; }

    public DateTime? dateTime { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: if i keep  *long Id*  its Limits my UserMessages to the size of long

Comment: How many messages do you have in the system? `long` has a max value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: if the chat has 1M users , every one message have id its possible,       how i make the *long Id* to be the ForeignKey, and not have 2 ids

Comment: If a chat has 1M users, and they each have 1M messages, and they do that on 1M different days, there would still be 8,223,372,036,854,775,807 different IDs that could still be used!

Comment: even you have [ForeignKey] ef force you to put  [Key] to?

Comment: Yep. That's the deal. Plus, if you did have the ID of the message being the User's ID, that would make it a 1:1 relationship in your database, which I don't think is your intention here.

Comment: so how can i make the [ForeignKey] and  [Key] to be one key, that ef will number the messages like this   k(1)  fk(1) , k(1) fk(2) , k(1) fk(3)

Comment: What I'm telling you is that you **don't want it as one key**. EF will think that you're trying to make it a 1:1 relationship with `User`, which you don't want (you currently have a 1:Many between them).